# Applying Newton-Raphson method to system of two differential equations, one time independent, one time dependent

Tags: newton-method

The goal is to couple system of two nonlinear differential equations by applying appropriate space and time discretization and Newton-Raphson scheme.

The equations system is
$$\left[
\begin{array}{c}
F_{1}(u,v)       \\
F_{2}(u,v)
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= v     \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}
&=\frac{\partial J(u,v)}{\partial x}
\end{aligned}
\right]
$$
where $u(x,t), v(x,t)$ is function of time and space.

Notice $F_{1}$ is differential equation in space exclusively, and $F_{2}$ is partial differential equation in space and time.

The discretization in space and time are subscript $i$ and superscript $j$ respectively.

For $F_1$, discretizing in space gives
$$
F_{1}(u,v)\quad\rightarrow\quad
\frac{u_{i+1}-2u_{i}+u_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2}+v_{i}=0
$$
The next is discretizing $F_2$ in space.
$$
F_{2}(u,v)\quad\rightarrow\quad
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}
=
\frac{J_{i+1}-J_{i}}{\Delta x}
$$

The assumption is made; $J_{i+1}$ is function of $u_{i}$, $u_{i+1}$, $v_{i}$ and $v_{i+1}$ and  $J_{i}$ is function of $u_{i-1}$, $u_{i}$, $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{i}$.

In discretizing $F_{2}$ in time, the method TR-BDF2(Trapezoidal Rule - Second-order Backward Differentiation Formula) is applied, which is
$$
\frac{\partial q(z)}{\partial t}
=
f(z,t)
\quad\rightarrow\quad
\frac{q^{j+1}-q^{j}}{\Delta t}=
\frac{f^{j+1}+f^{j}}{2}
\quad\rightarrow\quad
2q^{j+1}-\Delta t f^{j+1}
-2q^{j}-\Delta t f^{j}
=0
$$

Once again, superscript $j$ and $j+1$ denotes discretization in time, not power.

Applying TR-BDF2 method to space discretized $F_{2}$ gives
$$
F_{2}(u,v)\quad\rightarrow\quad
2v_{i}^{j+1}- \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(J_{i+1}^{j+1}-J_{i}^{j+1})
-2v_{i}^{j}- \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(J_{i+1}^{j}-J_{i}^{j})
=0
$$

Now, there are two equations, one in only discretized in space and the other discretized in both time and space. How do these two equations be coupled in Newton-Raphson scheme?

Does applying TR-BDF2 to $F_{1}$ valid? Since $F_{1}$ has to remain invariant through time...

Anyway, $q$ is zero in $F_{1}$, so $f^{j+1}+ f^{j}=0$ (??) Then there are two equations both in time and space discretized.
$$
F_{1}(u,v)\quad\rightarrow\quad
\frac{u_{i+1}^{j+1}-2u_{i}^{j+1}+u_{i-1}^{j+1}}{\Delta x^2}+v_{i}^{j+1}
+\frac{u_{i+1}^{j+1}-2u_{i}^{j}+u_{i-1}^{j}}{\Delta x^2}+v_{i}^{j}
=0
$$
$$
F_{2}(u,v)\quad\rightarrow\quad
2v_{i}^{j+1}- \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(J_{i+1}^{j+1}-J_{i}^{j+1})
-2v_{i}^{j}- \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(J_{i+1}^{j}-J_{i}^{j})
=0
$$
Applying Newton-Raphson Scheme method to this system is,
$$
u^{k+1}=u^{k}+\delta u^{k},
\qquad\qquad
\left[
\mathbf{J}(u^{k})
\right]\delta u^{k}
=
-
\left[
\mathbf{F}(u^{k})
\right]
$$

where Jacobian and $\mathbf{F}$ is

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{*{8}c}
U_{1D} & U_{1U} &        &       & V_{1D} &      &      &       \\
U_{1L} & U_{1D} & U_{1U} &       &        &V_{1D}&      &       \\
       & U_{1L} & \ddots & U_{1U}&        &      &\ddots&      \\ 
       &        & U_{1L} & U_{1D}&        &      &      &V_{1D}\\
U_{2D} & U_{2U} &        &       & V_{2D} &V_{2U}&      &         \\
U_{2L} & U_{2D} & U_{2U} &       & V_{2L} &V_{2D}&V_{2U}&          \\
       & U_{2L} & \ddots & U_{2U}&        &V_{2L}&\ddots&V_{2U}  \\ 
       &        & U_{2L} & U_{2D}&        &      &V_{2L}&V_{2D}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\delta u_2\\
\vdots \\
\delta u_{n-1}\\
\delta v_2\\
\vdots \\
\delta v_{n-1}
\end{array}
\right]
=
-
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
F_1(i=2)\\
\vdots\\
F_1(i=n-1)\\
F_2(i=2)\\
\vdots\\
F_2(i=n-1)
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $F_{1,2}(i)$ vector is inserting current $i$ value for $j$ terms and guess value $i$ for $j+1$ (next time) terms.

and each components are (D=main diagonal, U=first upper diagonal, L=first lower diagonal)

$$
\begin{aligned}
U_{1D}
&=
\frac{d}{du_i^{j+1}}F_{1}^{j+1}
=-\frac{2}{\Delta x^2}
& (2\leq i\leq n-1)
\\
U_{1U}
&=
\frac{d}{du_{i+1}^{j+1}}F_{1}^{j+1}
=\frac{1}{\Delta x^2}
& (2\leq i\leq n-2)
\\
U_{1L}
&=
\frac{d}{du_{i-1}^{j+1}}F_{1}^{j+1}
=\frac{1}{\Delta x^2}
& (3\leq i\leq n-1)
\\
V_{1D}
&=
\frac{d}{dv_{i}^{j+1}}F_{1}^{j+1}
=1
& (2\leq i\leq n-1)
\\
U_{2D}
&=
\frac{d}{du_i^{j+1}}F_{2}^{j+1}
=-\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(
\frac{dj_{i+1}^{j+1}}{du_{i}^{j+1}}
-
\frac{dj_{i}^{j+1}}{du_{i}^{j+1}}
\right)
& (2\leq i\leq n-1)
\\
U_{2U}
&=
\frac{d}{du_{i+1}^{j+1}}F_{2}^{j+1}
=-\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(
\frac{dj_{i+1}^{j+1}}{du_{i+1}^{j+1}}
\right)
& (2\leq i\leq n-2)
\\
U_{2L}
&=
\frac{d}{du_{i-1}^{j+1}}F_{2}^{j+1}
=\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(
\frac{dj_{i-1}^{j+1}}{du_{i-1}^{j+1}}
\right)
& (3\leq i\leq n-1)
\\
V_{2D}
&=
\frac{d}{dv_i^{j+1}}F_{2}^{j+1}
=2-\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(
\frac{dj_{i+1}^{j+1}}{dv_{i}^{j+1}}
-
\frac{dj_{i}^{j+1}}{dv_{i}^{j+1}}
\right)
& (2\leq i\leq n-1)
\\
V_{2U}
&=
\frac{d}{dv_{i+1}^{j+1}}F_{2}^{j+1}
=-\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(
\frac{dj_{i+1}^{j+1}}{dv_{i+1}^{j+1}}
\right)
& (2\leq i\leq n-2)
\\
V_{2L}
&=
\frac{d}{dv_{i-1}^{j+1}}F_{2}^{j+1}
=\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(
\frac{dj_{i-1}^{j+1}}{dv_{i-1}^{j+1}}
\right)
& (3\leq i\leq n-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Again,  $J_{i+1}$ is function of $u_{i}$, $u_{i+1}$, $v_{i}$ and $v_{i+1}$ and  $J_{i}$ is function of $u_{i-1}$, $u_{i}$, $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{i}$.

Is this correct way?